# How to ask about quality of security related qualifications or courses?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask a question about "how do I know a course or qualification is any good?"; but I'd like it to be a good fit for SE.

The specific courses I have in mind are the Backtrack Wifu course, and the MyHardDriveDied course.  But I wouldn't ask about those two specifically.

So, Security.SE, how should I formulate my question?

*How do I know if a security course is any good and / or leads to a respected qualification?*

Comment: you might be best off asking this in chat, as it isn't a good fit for the SE model - it is pretty subjective. That said, we do have some historical questions which might give you the answer you want. I think the education tag might be the one you want

Comment: Come visit us in the DMZ for that: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  Feel free to clsoe this now.  I knew it wasn't a good fit for SE.

Comment: Closed as per request - localised and subjective.